# Object property has <type 'property'>

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

I have a class with a string property defined on it.

```python
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def kind(self):
        return 'bar'
```

There's some third party code that I want to pass this property to that asserts that the property is a `str`:

third party:

```
def baz(kind):
    if not isinstance(kind, (str, unicode)):
        message = ('%.1024r has type %s, but expected one of: %s' %
                   (kind, type(kind), (str, unicode)))
        raise TypeError(message)
```

me:

```
foo = Foo()
baz(foo.kind)
```

output:

```
TypeError: <property object at 0x11013e940> has type <type 'property'>, but expected one of: (<type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>)
```

Is there any way I can make the python object have a property with `str` type rather than `property` type?

## EDIT:

Original question is wrong, I was actually calling

```
Foo.kind
```

as pointed out by Martijn Pieters below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing the property *directly on the class*:

```
>>> Foo.kind
<property object at 0x104a22c00>
>>> baz(Foo.kind)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in baz
TypeError: <property object at 0x104a22c00> has type <type 'property'>, but expected one of: (<type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>)
```

If you actually had an instance, the function you posted works just fine:

```
>>> Foo().kind
'bar'
>>> baz(Foo().kind)
```

That's because only when a property is bound to an instance does it use the getter function when accessed. When bound to a class the `property` object is returned directly.

Also see [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

Comment: Yep, my question was wrong -- I was indeed accessing the method from the class rather than an instance. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def kind(self):
        return 'bar'

def baz(kind):
    if not isinstance(kind, (str, unicode)):
        message = ('%.1024r has type %s, but expected one of: %s' %
                   (kind, type(kind), (str, unicode)))
        raise TypeError(message)


foo = Foo()
print foo.kind

baz(foo.kind)


--output:--
bar
```